# " Be alone " vs "be lonely "

Tags: differences, adjectives

> I am **alone**.
>
> I am **lonely**.

Do they have the same meaning? What is the difference between *alone* and *lonely*?

Comment: No - most of the time they *don't* have the same meaning. You're ***alone*** if there's no-one with you, regardless of how you feel about this. But you're ***lonely*** if you feel the lack of companionship, regardless of how many people might be in the vicinity. *A man is never so lonely as in a crowd of strangers*. You could have looked that up in any dictionary.

Comment: Nobody ever says they want to be lonely. "I want to be alone," means that people (even friends) would be an unhelpful distraction..

Comment: Hi, neil. All your questions except one have been closed. If you are a speaker of other languages learning English, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on English Language Learners. If you keep asking off-topic questions without your own research, you can be blocked from asking a question further.

Answer (score 4):

When you are alone, there is nobody with you. This is a physical property.

When you are lonely, you feel that you need company. This is a psychological property.

Comment: As Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.'